# aws quicksight command line not giving any result

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-quicksight

Trying to create a template to duplicate an analysis and getting nowhere using cli...
I need describe-dashboard to get the arn of the datasource for example, but it doesn't describe anything (the dashboard exists of course). And even when I guess the datasource arn, the command create-template gives the same "Status: 200" answer without creating the template.

1°) describe-dashboard and create-template use wrong endpoint:

```
https://quicksight.us-est-1.amazonaws.com/accounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/templates/xxxxxx
```

2°) Even when correcting it it only returns

```
{"Status": 200}
```

without any info on the dashboard or template... Does someone have any pointers ?

Example :

```
aws quicksight describe-dashboard --aws-account-id "xxxxxxx" --region "us-est-1" --dashboard-id "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --endpoint-url "https://us-east-1.quicksight.aws.amazon.com/sn/dashboards/"
```

Comment: can you rephrase the question to tell what are you trying to achieve and what is the error>?

Comment: I tried to clarify it. Is it clearer now ?